# .on("click", "img", function (e) not working after Postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following JQuery code :-

```
 $('.rpItem').on("click", "img", function (e) {
    alert('here');
    var text = $(this).siblings('span.rpText').text();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var args = {
        reportName: text
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Dashboard.aspx/AddToFavourites",
        data: JSON.stringify(args),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
        success: function (data) {
            __doPostBack('#MainMenuUP', text);
            //__doPostBack('<%= MainMenuUP.ClientID %>', text);
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
});


$("#reports_textSearch").keyup(function () {
    var textLength = $(this).val().length;
    delay(function () {

        if (textLength == 0) {
            emptySearchString();
        }

        if (textLength > 2) {
            var args = {
                reportName: document.getElementById('reports_textSearch').value
            };
            doSearchString(args);
        }
    }, 1000);

});

function doSearchString(args) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Dashboard.aspx/FetchReports",
        data: JSON.stringify(args),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //__doPostBack('#MainMenuUP', data.d);
            __doPostBack('<%= MainMenuUP.ClientID %>', data.d);  
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

and the first time its working fine.  However after the postback, the doSearch keeps on working correctly, whilst the

```
$('.rpItem').on("click", "img", function (e) {
```

fails.  It is not even going through that code.

I tried to replace the

```
__doPostBack('<%= MainMenuUP.ClientID %>', data.d);
```

with

```
__doPostBack('<%= MainMenuUP.UniqueID %>', data.d);
```

but that just does a page refresh which I do not want.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you adding a new `.rpItem` element in the callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your selector to this one:

```
$('body').on("click", ".rpItem img", function (e) {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: To clarify, change your selector to initially target an element that isn't being replaced by your postback.

Comment: @Mojtaba, the click works but its giving me a page refresh which I do not want

Comment: @Kevin, did not understand what you mean

Comment: @Johann Maybe your `__doPostBack` function refresh the page. Check that in your .NET codes.

Comment: @Mojtaba, please ignore my prev comment, its working, had the wrong __doPostback code, that is why it was refreshing the page.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Johann Accepting my answer as the correct answer is your  
kindness.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.rpItem` is replaced during your ajax call read the following:

The first time your js executes, it binds the `on` event to the existing rpItems.
Any new added `.rpItem`will skip this binding unless you re-execute the script that accomplishes the binding.

In order to avoid this, you may use the document for the binding as @Mojtaba suggests but keep in mind that you "add" the binding to the document leading to "checking" whether an .rpItem img has been clicked or not **every** time something is clicked on the document.

Otherwise, you can create a function that will take your .rpItem as an argument and will accomplish the binding explicitly. After each new .rpItem added to your page, you can call this function to bind the click event. Ex:

```
function foo(arg) {
  $(arg).on("click", "img", function (e) {
  ...
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rpItem').each(function(){
       foo($(this));
    };

});
```